# Is the conditional probability of a function of independent random variables equal to the marginal probability?

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, and let $Z = f(X,Y)$, where $f$ is an arbitrary function. Is the following statement true?

$$
p(z|y) = p(f(x,y)|y) = p(x)
$$

If it is true/false, how can I show this?

---

@ArnoV's answer explains what I meant.

Comment: Does it matter if it is a probability mass function or a probability density function?

Comment: The result is incorrect for both cases and meaningless: it does not explain how $z$ and $x$ are connected within the equation.

Comment: In order to have only $p(x)$ you must somehow integrate out the $y$ from $p(f(x,y)|y)$ otherwise, at least I don't see, how $y$ disappears?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you probably insinuate is the fact that, once $Y=y$ is known, the pdf of $Z\mid Y$ is uniquely determined through a transformation of $X$'s pdf.

In the (rare) case that $z = f(x,y) = \varphi_y(x)$ is an invertible relationship for each $y$ (namely $\varphi_y^{-1}$ exists for every $y$), you have that

$$ p_{Z\mid Y}(z\mid y) = p_{\varphi_y(X)}(z) = \lvert \dfrac{\partial}{\partial z}\varphi_y^{-1}(z)\rvert\, p_X(\varphi_y^{-1}(z))$$
using the change of variable formula.

So, in a sense, $Z\mid Y$ is uniquely determined by $\varphi_Y(\cdot) = f(\cdot, Y)$ and $p_X$ the distribution of $X$.